# After hiding parts of the div remains

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

A colleague of mine created a template with angularjs. It consists of menus, that can be closed. This is achieved by simple jQuery. However after clicking the close button the lower part of the menu-div remains. If the mouse is moved it disappears. I can't reproduce the error in a js fiddle. Why do parts still remain, how to fix this?

HTML

```
<div class="menu">
   <button class="close"> X close this </button>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.menu{
    width: 100px;
    height: 200px;
    padding: 20px;
    background: lightgrey;
}

.hide{
    display: none;
}
```

JS

```
$('body').on('click', '.close', function(){
    $(this).closest('.menu').addClass('hide'); 
});

/// also does not work
$('body').on('click', '.close', function(){
    $(this).closest('.menu').hide(); 
});
```

Comment: why not use the hide function?

Comment: Not sure if it will have any effect here, but never use `'body'` for delegated events. Use `document` instead. The `body`'s styling can cause events to not fire (especially click)

Comment: Can you include the parts that cause the issue? As you said, it's [not reproduce-able in JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/adnywjg6/). It'll just be a guessing game for us.

Comment: The whole point of AngularJS is to abstract the logic from the HTML through declarative data binding. If this was built using AngularJS, you should really be using the [`ngShow`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngShow) directive as oppose to `.show()` and `.hide()`. If `ngShow` does not work, consider creating a custom directive to accomplish this task.

Comment: @Ninsly I tried hide(), both does create the error

Comment: @War10ck you are right, now it works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all you are using angularjs, and you cannot use jQuery as on standard web sites. 
you have this JS:

```
$('body').on('click', '.close', function(){
    $(this).closest('.menu').addClass('hide'); 
});
```

but in moment when this script is executed there is no HTML rendered to page, so this script is usless.

You need to create a custom directive in order to make this work.

```
.directive('ngHideCustom', function () {
    return function (scope, elm, attrs) {
        $('.close', elm).click(function () {
            $(this).parent().hide();
        });
    }
})
```

and you need to change the html to call this directive

```
<div class="menu" ng-hide-custom>
   <button class="close"> X close this </button>
</div>
```

this way your script will be applied only when this part of HTML is rendered to page.

Comment: Re: *"there is no HTML rendered to page"*, does that mean if they had used `document` for the delegated event handler, it would have worked? (as `document` does exists at that time and it is a delegated handler).